# uc-words in select2 tag

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, jquery-select2

I have a select-2 tag in my hbs file in which  I populate results of a service call. The service returns the results in all capital letters which I have to change to Camel case. 
Previously I was using simple select html tag and hence could use uc-words helper to achieve this.

```
    <select onchange={{action "doSomething" value="target.value"}}>
        <option value="">Any</option>
        {{#each fruits as |fruit|}}
                <option value={{fruit.id}}>{{uc-words fruit.value force=true}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
```

Now on changing to select-2 hbs tag

```
    {{select-2
        content=fruits 
        optionLabelPath="value" searchEnabled=false
        optionValuePath="id"
        value=selectedFruit
        placeholder="Any"
        allowclear=true
    }}
```

Do I have a way to change this to camel case as well?

Also can I have an empty option without modifying the results?

Comment: if possible modify fruits before passing it to select-2. it will work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your time frame, and how elegant of a solution you want, you have a few choices.

If getting the job done quickly is what you want, just have a look at the [uc-words helper source](https://github.com/ChrisHonniball/ember-string-helpers/blob/master/addon/helpers/uc-words.js) and you can copy that function to your utils directory.

Then in your service, before you populate the appropriate property, just transform the set of fruits values with the function linked above.

The function, copied and adjusted for your use case:

```
// utils/helpers.js
export function ucWords(word, options) {
  var string =  String(word),
    force = (options.force === true) ? true : false;

  if(force) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
  }

  return string.replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
  });
}

// services/populate.js
//..
import { ucWords } from 'utils/helpers.js'

export default Service.extend({

  fruitStore: service(),

  upperCaseFruit: Ember.computed('fruitStore.fruits', function(){
    return this.get('fruitStore.fruits').map(fruit => {
        fruit.value = ucWords(fruit.value);
        return fruit;
    });
  })

})
```

Comment: Can I have an empty option without modifying the results? Can it be handled in the tag itself?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to know if there is a direct way for using that helper with select 2 tag